# Angular test keyup does not working

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine

I have a simple component with input. I want to test some functionality on keyup, but when I run the test with Chrome, I don't see any output on the input.

```
  it('should be...', function () {
    const input = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'));
    input.triggerEventHandler('keydown', {
      keyCode: 67
    });
    input.triggerEventHandler('keyup', {
      keyCode: 67
    });

    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

What I am missing?

Comment: Where are your assertions?

Comment: That doesn't matter, I don't see the key on the input in my browser so it's not working

Comment: Anyway, I would add a simple assertion just to be sure, because it might skip the tests without assertions. Otherwise I don't see any reason why the event is not triggering.

Comment: I added assertion and it's still don't work

Comment: I've just found a similar code from Angular's official examples. There it always calls `fixture.detectChanges()` at the beginning of `it()` and then the rest, in your case after triggering the event.

Comment: @ng2user did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem. Please post your solution if you have it.